# Is it possible in PostgreSQL or SQL to dump a list of values into a single column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking for a PostgreSQL or SQL command that will allow me to dump an ordered list of values in to a single column. I tried running the below `INSERT` command but received the following error response:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (test_column) VALUES ('test01', 'test02', 'test03');
```

> ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm working with a large set of dictionary key-values that I'm trying to insert into a SQL database and I'm unsure of the best way to make this happen.

Comment: What do *you* mean by least?  Postgres supports arrays, records, and JSON.  So, yes, you can have multiple values in a single column.

Comment: If you have a mix of lists and key/value pairs use a JSONB column. Or even better, normalize your model and store the information in a properly normalized model

Comment: That's a good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want one column, but three rows.  The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (test_column)
    VALUES ('test01'), ('test02'), ('test03');
```

Comment: Ah, so I need to ensure the outputs are separate from one another. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a JSON data type, for more info refer to [link](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/)

Comment: Thanks rachid. I was somewhat leaning towards this but it would be essentially taking a dictionary and laying it out across an entire table for processing.